# Xamarin.Froms app won't launch on iPhone to debug

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

After a few minor VS 2019 on Windows updates I cannot debug iOS app on real device anymore. It says:

> You must now execute:
> lldb -s /tmp/mtouch-lldb-prep-cmds

[image]

What's going on here? How to launch & debug app on iPhone? Debug won't launch app but deploys it and I can launch the app manually without debugging.

I use VS 2019 on Windows and pair VS with Mac.

Comment: Sometimes this method works: stop paring with the Mac, delete "bin" and "obj" folders from the iOS and Mobile projects, pair it again and build the solution

Comment: Hi , what's the version of Xamarin Forms and the real iPhone ? You can have a try with other real iPhone devices to check whehter can debug .In addition, before debuging , uninstalling the previous veresion of app to have a try .